# Do We Have To Store User Password In The Device For Using Odoo 12 External API?

Tags: android, rest, odoo-12

I want to create a mobile app with Odoo 12 as a backend system. So I search Odoo External API and I found this [Odoo External Api Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/webservices/odoo.html). As we can see there we need to pass user password as a parameter everytime we call `execute_kw`. Does it means that we need to store user's password inside user's device? I think storing the password in the device reduce the security. Any other solution?